# Always getting same predicted probability (LibSVM)

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, libsvm

I am trying to predict the class of some instances in a binary problem (I have two classes: C+ and C-). I am using a libSVM classifier trained with a linear kernel.

Executing method distributionForInstance(instance) I get always the same predicted probability with the same classifier and different instances (I'm getting 0.56 for C+ and 0.44 for C-).

Any idea why?